# Algorithm:how to find the minimum number of combined number from a Char array so the number exceeds the target number?

Tags: algorithm

We have a char array. All chars in the array are from 0 to 9. For example : 1,9,2,3.

We need to find out the the minimum number of combined chars which is greater than the target value(for example :92), then the 93 is the value what I want.

one example : 1,9,2,3

target : 192

The minimum number which is greater than 192 : 193(i.e.:'1'+'9'+'3').

one more example:2,1,3

target :99

The minimum number which is greater than 99: 123

one more example:2,1,4

target :12

The minimum number which is greater than 12: 14

Please advice &help.

This is not home work, for sure. and there is no order in the char array.

for example:
target:23
the one i want:31

My question:do you need to find all possible combinations(two digit integer/three digit inters/four digit integer) and then find the closest integer to target number.

and length of char array could be 10. the target number could be greater than one million...

No  repeat characters are allowed For instance for target 10 will the answer be  12 instead of 11

Any ideas?

Comment: Do I get it right, that order in the array is to be preserved?

Comment: What have your tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Is this homework? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Do the characters need to be selected in the order in which they occur in the array?

Comment: Can you repeat characters? For instance for target 10 will the answer be 11 or it will be 12?

Comment: no repeat allowed.it should be 12

Comment: The order in the array is Not to be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Since no repeated digits are allowed, the very first thing to do is to remove repeated digits from the array. Also, sorting the array is a good idea.

If the target has `d` digits, the solution is either also a `d`-digit number or a `d+1`-digit number. If it's a `d+1` digit number, it is the smallest you can construct from the array values. That part is very easy:

```
digit[1] = minimum of nonzero array elements
for p = 2 to d+1:
    digit[p] = minimum of array elements not yet taken
```

If the solution is a `d`-digit number, its first digit is either equal to the first digit of the target, or it's larger. If it's larger, the constructed number will be larger than the target no matter what the following digits are, so for the remaining digits, you can copy part of the above case. If the first digit of the solution is equal to the first digit of the target, you have reduced the problem to that of finding a solution for a `d-1`-digit target with a smaller array of eligible digits. You can then recur.

Comment: Hi Daniel,thanks a lot for the update. i did not get the d+1 didgit?could you explain it more?why it's the smallest we can construct from the array values? any codes in java/c#/c++ would help me a lot as well

Comment: i just updated some example above..hope you can get what i am tring to say

Comment: If the target has `d` digits, any `d+1`-digit number is larger than the target. So no `d+1`-digit number except the smallest can be the solution. Taking the example array, 1,9,2,3, and the target 94, you can see that no 2-digit number larger than 94 can be constructed from the array digits. The 3-digit numbers constructible from the array are 123, 129, 132, 139, 192, 193, 213, ..., obviously 123 is the smallest.

Comment: got it thanks,Daniel,but do i need to enumerate all 3-digit numbers from the char array?

Comment: No, you don't need to enumerate them all. You know they all fulfill the "larger than target" requirement, so you need only find the smallest.

Comment: thanks,one more query,'Taking the example array, 1,9,2,3, and the target 94, you can see that no 2-digit number larger than 94' i guess we have to find a way to decide whether no 2-digit number larger than 94? and if target number is 12?

Comment: Yes, first you try to find a solution with the same number of digits as the target. Only if that fails, you go on to construct a `d+1`-digit number.

Comment: got it but this is too complicated ,is there a quick way to solve this?

Comment: thanks Daniel,could you pass me some sample code i can follow?

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic programming approach, preserving the order in the original array, you could work out, after the first N characters, the maximum number possible using only 1,2,3...N characters. Then for the N+1th position the maximum number possible with i characters is either as before, or the previous answer with i-1 characters extended with the current character.

A hack, if you don't have to preserve the order, is to sort the original array.

Example given 1923

At position 1 you care about 1.

At position 2 you care about 19 and 9.

At position 3 you care about 192, 92, and 9.

A the end you care about 1923, 923, and 93.

Further comments:
There is an article on dynamic programming at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming. The main idea is to solve small problems, and then use those solutions to solve slightly larger problems, and then use those... and so on until you have worked your way up to the problem you actually want to solve.

In your case, you want to find how to take a small number of characters from 1923 so as to make a large number. Suppose you know how to take a small number of characters from 192 to make a large number. In that case, the best solution for 1923 will either be a best solution for 192 or that solution with the 3 that ends 1923 added on. This is because if you had a solution for 1923 that was better than any of the ones you could get as I described, you could get a better solution for 192 by taking it, and perhaps deleting its final character.

Of course, at the beginning you don't know the solution for 192 either, so you have to start at the very beginning, with the solution for 1, and from that work out the best solutions for 19, and then 192, and finally for 1923 - which is what I have shown in the example above.

Finally, I couldn't work out from your question whether e.g. 9321 or 932 are possible solutions. If they are, the problem is easier, but if you really want to you can solve it with much the same method. Just sort 1923 to give 9321 and then solve that as you solved for 1923.

Comment: HI MCdowella,thanks a lot for your comment,but i did not get it. could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: (Added more explanation to answer)